# Playsound does not work when the block value is set to false

Tags: python, playsound, python-playsound

okaayy so im working on a music player but it not working as i want
so the problem is when i play the music using the playsound library it blocks the code from running and freezes the tkinter window but i searched and found out that you can set block to False but when it set to false the music doesn't play.

here is the code:

```
from playsound import playsound as psound
#a loop here where i get the directory of musics and create a button for every music and each of the button's command value is set to the 'play_sound' function and passing the music directory as argument
    def play_aux(self, dir):
        psound(dir, False)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also specify any third party libraries and links to external resources that you are referencing.

Comment: okayy umm i took some code out is it good now or should i add the loop?

Answer (score -1):

Okay so i got it working but idk how to check if the sound is still playing so i switched to pygame and it working fine for me!